# How to make intersection table on PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, intersection

Here's my dataset

```
Name      Order
A         Coffee
A         Tea
A         Burger
A         Fried Chicken
B         Coffee
B         Tea
B         Hot Dog
B         Fried Chicken
C         Coffee
C         Hot Dog
C         Fried Chicken
D         Tea
D         Burger
```

Here's the Info

```py
Food = ['Hot Dog', 'Burger', 'Fried Chicken'] # Rows
Drink = ['Coffee', 'Tea'] # Colums
```

Here's the expected output

```
            Hot Dog    Burger   Fried Chicken
Tea             0.5        1             0.66
Coffee            1      0.5               1
```

`Hot Dog x Tea` is `0.5` because among 2 People Buying `Hot Dog` only one Buying `Tea` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow it feels there should be a nice way to do it, maybe using [`crosstab`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crosstab.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crosstab)...

But I could only think of the following quite big algorithm. Even though it uses external `itertools` library, it should perform well, because that part resides inside a [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) which is vectorized for performance.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 'Coffee'),
     ('A', 'Tea'),
     ('A', 'Burger'),
     ('A', 'Fried Chicken'),
     ('B', 'Coffee'),
     ('B', 'Tea'),
     ('B', 'Hot Dog'),
     ('B', 'Fried Chicken'),
     ('C', 'Coffee'),
     ('C', 'Hot Dog'),
     ('C', 'Fried Chicken'),
     ('D', 'Tea'),
     ('D', 'Burger')],
    ['Name', 'Order'])
```

Script:

```py
@F.pandas_udf('array<array<string>>')
def pudf(c: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return c.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))

df = df.groupBy('Name').agg(F.collect_set('Order').alias('Order'))
beverages = ['Coffee', 'Tea']
df = df.withColumn('Order', F.transform(pudf('Order'), lambda x: F.when(x[1].isin(beverages), F.array(x[1], x[0])).otherwise(x)))
df = df.withColumn('Order', F.filter('Order', lambda x: x[0].isin(beverages) & ~x[1].isin(beverages)))
df = df.withColumn('Order', F.explode('Order'))
df = df.select('Name', F.col('Order')[0].alias('beverage'), F.col('Order')[1].alias('food'))
df = df.withColumn('food_cnt', F.size(F.collect_set('Name').over(W.partitionBy('food'))))
df = (df
    .groupBy('beverage')
    .pivot('food')
    .agg(F.round(F.count(F.lit(1)) / F.first('food_cnt'), 2))
)
df.show()
# +--------+------+-------------+-------+
# |beverage|Burger|Fried Chicken|Hot Dog|
# +--------+------+-------------+-------+
# |     Tea|   1.0|         0.67|    0.5|
# |  Coffee|   0.5|          1.0|    1.0|
# +--------+------+-------------+-------+
```